# connect java application to mysql server in netbeans 6.8

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

i am beginner in java as well as in netbeans .please give me complete procedure how i can connect my java application to mysql to insert data .

Answer (score 1):

Download "mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar" from following link http://sqlworkbench.mgm-tp.com/viewvc/trunk/sqlworkbench/junit/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar?revision=2294&pathrev=2294

Following is a sample java code to connect to a mysql database and retrieve data from a table.

In below code database name is  "databaseName"

and table name is "userTable"

Dont forget to add "mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar" to your netbeans project's libraries.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class NewClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Connection conn = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/";
    String dbName = "databaseName";
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String databaseUserName = "root";   //user name to connect to database(plz change it with your mysql username)
    String databasePassword = "root";   //password to connect to database(plz change it with your mysql password)
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, databaseUserName, databasePassword);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        result = null;
        String password,username;
        result = stmt.executeQuery("select * from userTable ");
        if(!result.isBeforeFirst()){
            System.out.println("resultset contin no rows");
        }else{ // result set contain some data.... ie.. table contain some rows
            // process data
        }

        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11920142/419

Comment: Above answer is correct for this question too ... that's why i pasted it here too...

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans' knowledge base article describing [how to connect to a mysql database](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/mysql.html).